# UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT user lacks privilege or object not found: PERSONSET in statement [UPDATE PersonSET address = 'null ' WHERE name = 'null ']

Tags: java, sqlexception, ucanaccess

```
package jdbcex;
import java.sql.*;
public class JdbcDmlEx {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr;
    arr = new String[3];

    try {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\access\\PersonInfo.accdb");

    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

    //execute the query / DML

    String addVar = arr[0];
    String nameVar = arr[1];

    String sql = "UPDATE Person" +
                 "SET address =  '" + addVar + " ' " +
                 "WHERE name = '" + nameVar + " ' " ;

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    int num = pstmt.executeUpdate();

// process the results of the query
System.out.println(num + " records updated");

conn.close();

    }catch(Exception sqlEx) {
        System.out.println(sqlEx);
    }
}//end of main
}//end of class
```

Can't understand what the problem is. Can someone help?

> UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT user lacks privilege or object not found: PERSONSET in statement [UPDATE PersonSET address =  'null' WHERE name = 'null']

Keep getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
 "UPDATE Person" +
```

to this:

```
 "UPDATE Person " +
```